# What is the purpose of Stanza IDs in XMPP?

Tags: xml, xmpp

Can someone explain what purpose do ID's serve in some of XMPP XML requests (talking about core XMPP)?

For example, I can fetch roster by sending this request:

```
<iq type="get">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"></query>
</iq>
```

But I can also fetch it by adding a random ID:

```
<iq type="get" id="2346543">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"></query>
</iq>
```

Is there a reason as to why should or shouldn't I use ID's? Is it security related? Are there any drawbacks? What is the convention about ID's and how should they be constructed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend simply looking into the protocol specification. [RFC 6120 § 8.1.3. id](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-8.1.3) explains it pretty nicely IMHO:

> The 'id' attribute is used by the originating entity to track any
> response or error stanza that it might receive in relation to the
> generated stanza from another entity (such as an intermediate server
> or the intended recipient).
>
> It is up to the originating entity whether the value of the 'id'
> attribute is unique only within its current stream or unique
> globally.
>
> For <message/> and <presence/> stanzas, it is RECOMMENDED for the
> originating entity to include an 'id' attribute; for <iq/> stanzas,
> it is REQUIRED.
>
> If the generated stanza includes an 'id' attribute then it is
> REQUIRED for the response or error stanza to also include an 'id'
> attribute, where the value of the 'id' attribute MUST match that of
> the generated stanza.

Not that your example showing an IQ stanza without an 'id' attribute set is actually **invalid**.

Answer (score 2):

When you send an IQ with **type="get"** or **type="set"** then you will receive a response with **type="result"** and the same id

So this is just to match responses to their requests, by id.

For example,

get roster:

```
<iq type="get" id="2346543">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"></query>
</iq>
```

response:

```
<iq to='icq.exampel.com' from='juliet@example.com' type='result' id='2346543'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'>
    <item jid='123456789@icq.example.com'
          name='Romeo'
          subscription='both'>
      <group>Friends</group>
    </item>
    <item jid='554323654@icq.example.com'
          name='Mercutio'
          subscription='from'>
      <group>Friends</group>
    </item>
    <item jid='997665667@icq.example.com'
          name='Benvolio'
          subscription='both'>
      <group>Friends</group>
    </item>
  </query>
</iq>
```

they contain the same id so you know for what request this response is